# Real Time ML Pipeline Structure

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, pipeline, data-analysis

So we have two datasets for which we train our ML models manually at the moment. One dataset is saved to the MySQL database server and it does not get updated and the other dataset gets new data points once in a while and ML modes make predictions based on that.

We would like to automate the second dataset-type ML predictions.

So the current flow is as follows:

1. Get the data from several tables in MySQL and merge them into one with some SQL scripts with the start of Jupyter Notebook
2. Read that raw data to the Jupyter Notebook and do some data cleaning (it is usually text-related regex rules stuff - this part usually changes from one setup to another)
3. Do some data analysis reports before the model is created
4. Training the model and get the predictions
5. Save all possible predictions generated by the model to MySQL and serve the predictions based on the incoming API request.

We do this setup for each client we have and as you can see it is tedious there are so many repeating points except the regex part as it has to be based on the client's needs. Also, we have to save all possible predictions to the database rather than running the model each time a request comes in and make a prediction based on what the model is trained.

I would be super happy if you guys could direct me to the right sources to start with and have a fully scalable ML pipeline so that most of the things are taken care of automatically.